# Why does hyphenation seems not to work on larger \textwidth?

Tags: hyphenation

Here is the minimal example, it appears that the hyphenation does not work properly here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9.0in}, headsep=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'Nothing to do here': the log shows now overfull boxes so TeX doesn't hyphenate (you can see more details by tracing the run). Of course, hyphenation of cod-Latin using English patterns is going to be a bit odd anyway.

Comment: Well, there are some huge strange white spaces, and even when i type something in english the hyphenation wont kick in.

Comment: The screenshot is fine so please post a short example which shows this issue, and ideally the log to go with it.

Comment: As @JosephWright points out that hyphenating `lipsum` text might be a bit troublesome, perhaps you might get clearer results with[`kantlipsum'](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kantlipsum) which uses English words.

Answer (score 3):

TeX puts some penalty on each hyphen, so it avoids hyphenation when it is not really necessary. And, in this example, hyphenation is indeed not needed: There are neither overful nor underful hboxen.

The large spaces you are noticing are spaces after a full stop at the end of sentence (an example is the space after *Cras nec ante.*). Turn on `\frenchspacing` (by using this command in the preamble) to make the spaces after a full stop equal to normal word spaces.

Comment: The problem was with \frenchspacing. Now the text looks like i want it to. Thanks